# if a value is set by 'set' method of Class java.lang.reflect.Field, does it have visibility in concurrency?

Tags: java, reflection, concurrency, apache-zookeeper

In java doc of this method, concurrency is not mentioned, so it seems that the 'set' method do not ensure visibility. I'm not sure about this.

In fact, I have encountered a difficulty because of this question. I'm going to build a distribute configuration platform based on zookeeper. Like the other configuration platform, if a field is annotated by a specific annotation, the platform will mapping this field to a node in zookeeper. Once the value of the mapped node is changed, project using this platform will be informed by zookeeper watcher and change the annotated field using reflection(by 'set' method).

The project using my configuration platform is likely to be a web application, which has one and only one object in service layer, so the field is always accessed in concurrency. if the 'set' method do not ensure visibility, do I must force the project add Keyword **volatile** for the annotated field ? I looks strange and tedious. Is there some better way about this problem ? How do the other configuration platforms solving this ?

Comment: I do understand that one part of the app is **reacting** to changes to a private field; but where is the need coming from to **set** that field via reflection?

Comment: Other platforms are solving this with much more code than a single strange and tedious keyword.

Comment: @Marko Topolnik So, the visibility is really a problem, right ? Could you give me some more detailed guidance, about the idea of 'much more code' ?

Comment: Guidance? All the guidance you need is "add the `volatile` keyword".

Comment: @GhostCat Some web application may has uncertain configuration value. while the application is running, the value can be changed by the watcher of zookeeper. Whether the field is **private** is not important.

Comment: In that case, **volatile** sounds like your only option.

Comment: Technically `volatile` isn't the only option, but it sure as heck is the easiest one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> In java doc of this method, concurrency is not mentioned, so it seems that the 'set' method do not ensure visibility. I'm not sure about this.

Calling a `set` method through reflection has nothing to do with concurrency, it is about accessibility.  The concurrency is about how the field is specifically marked up.  Is it a `volatile` field, one of the `Atomic...` classes, etc.?

If one thread calls the `set` method in any way (`setFoo()` method, via reflection, or other code) then other threads may not see this updated value until the thread doing the writing crosses a write memory barrier to ensure publishing to main memory and the other threads cross a read barrier to ensure that their per-processor memory caches are updated.

> If the 'set' method do not ensure visibility, do I must force the project add Keyword volatile for the annotated field ?

Yes you do.  For *any* field that you want to share between threads you will need to figure out how the field gets synchronized.

> I looks strange and tedious. Is there some better way about this problem ? How do the other configuration platforms solving this ?

The answer to this depends a bit on your requirements.  If you need this field updated to the most recent value on every access then marking it `volatile` or switching to an `Atomic*` class is your answer (not sure why adding the keyword is "tedious").

Another mechanism you could use is to have each request update some sort of configuration object at the start of the request in a synchronized manner and then use it's cached config object while the request is being handled.

Comment: “other threads will not see this updated value until…” sounds like an absolute statement. It’s important to emphasize that there is no guaranty about whether they will see the updated value or not. That’s what opens the possibilities of arbitrary inconsistencies; a thread might read values of different up-to-dateness.

Comment: @Gray  The book _Java.Concurrency.in.Practice_ says that a thread may **never** see the value updated by the other thread, so I'm ambiguous about your word "at any time", does it means the real time, or my requirements? I  think `volatile' is indispensable if the field is accessed in concurrency. 
The solution which doing synchronizing before the request being handled is great!

Comment: I've edited my answer to change "at any time" to be "updated to the most recent value on every access" @s.one.ice.

Comment: I've changed "will" to "may" @Holger although the only other way a thread would see it is if it was context switche out or had other reasons to flush it's memory cache.

Comment: The most common reason to see an up-to-date value without synchronization is that the value wasn’t cached before, i.e. it is the first time the thread reads the variable. Besides that, on x86 the caches are sync’ed by hardware, so the main reasons not to see up-to-date values on x86 are a) HotSpot code transformations and b) the value is kept in a CPU register. Since CPU registers are scarce, it’s normal that only some variables are mapped to registers while others are re-read from the sync’ed cache, yielding different up-to-dateness.

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a fundamental misconception. In order to ensure visibility, *both* ends, i.e. the write *and* the subsequent read, must access the variable appropriately. There can’t be a magic setter that “ensures visibility” for a non-`volatile` variable. Declaring a variable `volatile` will force both, readers and writers, to ensure visibility.

It’s also unclear why declaring a variable as `volatile` to get `volatile` semantics looks “strange and tedious” to you. You don’t have to declare it as such, because of the change via Reflection, but because of the presence of changes needing inter-thread visibility in general.

Comment: I said it “strange and tedious” because I hope the concurrency issue to be transparent for the application. In other word, the application developer only need to declare a annotated field and import configuration platform dependencies, as visibility is ensured by the class of configuration platform.

Comment: The visibility can be ensured by the configuration platform, if it ensures that there is no concurrent access. E.g., the typical way of setting configuration fields *before* running any code of the class, will work flawlessly. Syncing the writes with the subsequent reads of the field will do as well. Just using Reflection to set fields won’t help anything about it and since you said, the framework will set the fields concurrently, you need to take action…